# Accessing certain properties of a SimpleXMLElement Object

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

When I `print_r()` the SimpleXMLElement Object referenced by variable `$xmlObject`, I see the following structure:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [uri] => /example
        )

    [result] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [message] => Record(s) added successfully
            [recorddetail] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    ...
                )
        )
)
```

Notice how the `$xmlObject->result->message` property looks like it is just a string. However, if I do `print_r($xmlObject->result->message)`, I get the following:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => Record(s) added successfully
)
```

So at this point I'm confused. Why is `$xmlObject->result->message` being identified as an instance of `SimpleXMLElement Object` in this case, when the result of printing the full `$xmlObject` doesn't suggest this?

And how do I actually access this value? I've tried `$xmlObject->result->message[0]`, but it just prints out the same thing (i.e. the last code snippet I posted).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The representation you get when using `print_r` or `var_dump` on a `SimpleXMLElement` has very little to do with how it is structured internally. For instance there is no property `@attributes` you could access with `$element['@attributes']['uri']` either. You just do `$element['uri']`

This is simply the way it is. `SimpleXmlElement` objects behave different. Make sure you read the examples in the PHP Manual before using SimpleXml:

- http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

To understand the implementation it in detail, you'd have to look at the source code:

- http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_TRUNK/ext/simplexml/simplexml.c

To print `$xmlObject->result->message` you just do `echo $xmlObject->result->message`. That will autocast the `SimpleXmlElement` to string.

Comment: +1 was just typing a similar answer. It's worth pointing out that if you want to assign the string value of an element to a variable you need to explicitly cast it to a string. eg `$message = (string)$xmlObject->result->message`