# Getting an elements inner text with SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, simplexml

I am trying to access the text value of a xml element. I am using `SimpleXMLElement`. I have to be missing something obvious.

```
<h:html xmlns:jr="http://openrosa.org/javarosa" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ex="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms">
  <h:head>
    <h:title>NewForm</h:title>      
  </h:head>
</h:html>

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($resp);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('h', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'); 
// I have tried with and without the namespace (it doesn't seem to make a difference)

$result = $xml->xpath('//h:title');
debug($result);
```

Running the code above gives me:

```
array (
  0 => 
  SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
     0 => 'NewForm',
  )),
)
```

Seems very simple.  I am having difficulty getting the value of the 'NewForm'

I have tried

`$result[0]`, `$result[0]->{0}`, `$result[0][0]`.

Iterating through the children of the `$result[0]`.

Could someone please help guide me in the correct direction so I can get the text from the title element?

Comment: An example of the XML you're working with would be helpful. And relating that to what you want to get out of it.

Comment: Also do a `print_r()` instead of `debug()` as that appears to be custom output (CakePHP?).

Comment: See as well: [Accessing certain properties of a SimpleXMLElement Object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9691847/367456)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This worked for me with your example:

```
echo (string)$result[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try casting to a string after selecting the item in the array:

```
[...]
$result = $xml->xpath('//h:title');
echo current($result);
```